# How to get NSAttributeDescription?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsentitydescription, nsattributedescription

I have a `User : NSManagedObject`. What's the best way to get an `NSAttributeDescription` of it's `userID` attribute?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have access to a `User *user` instance, you could do:

```
NSAttributeDescription *userIDAttribute =
    [[user.entity attributesByName] objectForKey:@"userID"];
```

If you didn't have access to a `User *user` object but just to the `NSManagedObjectContext *context`, you could get the `NSEntityDescription` for `User` with:

```
NSEntityDescription *userEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
```